# Unomi server not working after Restart of Unomi or Easticsearch Server

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-karaf, apache-unomi

I am having Unomi installed in my local system and sometimes when we restart either Unomi or Elasticsearch server, it starts behaving wierdly as below :

- **http://localhost:8181/context.json** starts showing CORS Exception.
- when we excute CURL command to create scope, it shows 200 status code but scope is not created.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in Advance.

Expectation is context.json should load properly.
Not aware about next step how to fix it.